# How to run Windows Ikev2 with NonetworkFirewall?

Tags: windows, vpn, firewall, windows-firewall, ikev2

I have a small problem.I setup [Firewall App Blocker](https://www.sordum.org/8125/firewall-app-blocker-fab-v1-7/) in whtielist Mode(means basically It cut all Internet except allowed apps by setting "block all connection that not match firewall rule" in windows firewall). After Setting on whitelist I See My OpenVPN and IKev2 not working(as expected).So I added Openvpn daemon in connection allowed list and Now my OpenVPN start working correctly.But when I added rasclient from system32 on allowed list Ikev2 is not working,It successfully connected but internet is not working.I even added whole system32 executables(that appear in front when open system32) in whitelists
but Ikev2 not working.

So Please tell me **which executable I allow to successfully connect Ikev2 like OpenVPN or any other rule to add in firewall to allow IKev2 connection without Disabling Whitelist Mode?**

Thanks for giving time to solve my Problem.

Comment: Are you using the Windows built-in IKEv2 client?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 the IKEv2 built-in client is a system service (running under an instance of svchost.exe) called ikeext and displayed as "IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules" in Services

Comment: Yes I am talking about windows built-in ikev2 client. As I said above I allow all my internet connection for all executables that are in system32 directory including svchost. and still vpn connect successfully but internet is not working. Can you suggest any so that I can allow connection for ikev2 vpn in firewall.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to enable split-tunnel if you aren't trying to use the internet through your VPN connection

Comment: Not work unfortunately